# Swift: Setting name, photo, and cover from Facebook JSON to variables is not working.

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to using the Facebook API, and I'm trying to make a profile page with the user's name, profile picture and cover photo all taken from Facebook. I was able to parse through the JSON data provided and get the name, cover url and picture url, but when I try and set them to IBOutlets that are in another class, it doesn't change anything. The UILabel and UIImageViews remain the same.`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, BWWalkthroughViewControllerDelegate, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

var profilePageViewController : profilePage!
var profileVC = profilePage()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let stb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)

    profilePageViewController = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profile") as! profilePage

    profileVC = profilePageViewController
}


// MARK: FACEBOOK DELEGATE

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {

    print("Logged out of Facebook")
}

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

    if error != nil{

        print(error)
        return
    }
}

func showFacebookInformation(){

    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, picture.type(large),cover"]).start(completionHandler: { (connction, result, error) in

        if(error != nil){
            print("Failed to start Graph API request", error)
            return
        }

        print(result)

        let result = result as! Dictionary<String,Any>

        // GETTING COVER PHOTO URL

        let cover = result["cover"] as! Dictionary<String,Any>
        let coverSource = cover["source"] as! String

        // GETTING NAME

        let name = result["name"] as! String

        // GETTING PROFILE PICTURE

        let picture = result["picture"] as! Dictionary<String,Any>
        let data = picture["data"] as! Dictionary<String,Any>
        let url = data["url"] as! String

        print("The profile picture URL is: ",url)
        print("The cover photo url is: ",coverSource)
        print("The name is: ",name)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.profileVC.profilePicture.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:url))
            self.profileVC.userName.text = name 
        }
    })
}

@IBAction func logUserIn(){

    FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile"], from: self) { (result, error) in

        if(error != nil){

            print("Facebook Login failed: ",error)
            return
        }
        else{
            self.profileVC.loadViewIfNeeded()
            self.showFacebookInformation()
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Pass the details through segue and assign the values to the outlets in that view controller's viewDidLoad(). You can't directly assign the values like this.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are trying to set UILabel and UIImageView from the Viewcontroller where you have instantiated rather pass the data to the to profile viewcontroller and set values there in its viewdidload or in viewwillappear methods. It is happening because the layout has not been prepared yet.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Doesn't the fact that I'm using self.profileVC.loadViewIfNeeded() already load the profile viewcontroller though?